# Sorting An Array of Objects Based on Multiple Parameters

Tags: php, csv, sorting, object

I'm trying to make an agenda of panelists for an event company - their site is made with PHP. They already have a CSV file which lists the panelist. I wrote some code so that they can just upload their CSV to their server and have it render as an table.

The csv is set up more or less like this:

```
Panel, Name, Last Name, Title, Company, Moderator
tuesday, John, Doe, Partner, Acme,1
tuesday, Jane, "O Reily", Partner, SkyNet,0
tuesday, Samatha, Klein, CEO, Sea World,0
tuesday, Bill, Clarke, Head of Marketing, TNT,0
wednesday, Mohammed, Algarisi, Managing Director, Cheesy Photos,1
wednesday, Tim, Draper, Founding and Managing Partner, Draper Associates,0
```

Anyhow, they want the panelists to be sorted alphabetically by last name, with the moderator displaying first. I'm having trouble doing this in PHP.

I'm not so used to PHP code so I'm sure I must be missing stuff, should I have set this up differently? What's the best way to sort it?

Here's basically what I did-

First I made a Panelist class:

```
class Panelist {

    function __construct($panel, $name, $lastname, $title, $company, $moderator){
        $this -> panel = $panel;
        $this -> name = $name;
        $this -> lastname = $lastname;
        $this -> title = $title;
        $this -> company = $company;
        $this -> moderator = $moderator;

    }

}
```

Then an empty array where we will store our Panelist objects
    $panelists =array();

```
$row = 1;
//accesses our csv file from which we will get the data for the objects
if(($handle = fopen("agenda.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    //loops through the csv file by row
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        //skips the header (first) row
        if($row == 1) {$row++; continue;}
        //instanciates a Panelist object for every row in the csv file
        $name = new Panelist($data[0], $data[1], $data[2], $data[3], $data[4], data[5] );
        //adds object to our $panelist array
        array_push($panelists, $name);

}
```

Then I have an output function that recieves two arguments:

```
1. $arr - the array where the objects are stored
2. $panelName - the name of the panel to output 


    function outputSpeakers($arr, $panelName){
 // loops through objects in $arr
    foreach($arr as $obj){
     //only outputs objects with a panel value matching $panelName:
        if($obj->panel == $panelName){
            $name = $obj->name;
            $lastname = $obj->lastname;
            $title = $obj->title;
            $company= $obj->company;
            //lots of condition formatting stuff here that's not important such as...
            if($obj->moderator == '1'){
               //if the moderator is "TBA" - don't output title or company:
                if($name == ' TBA'){
                    //format this way
                } //else ...
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Then, in my agenda.php file I include the above class file and do:

```
<div class="panel-list">
    <? outputSpeakers($panelist, "tuesday"); ?>
</div>
```

Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting there.

In brief, you can try this:

```
if ($obj->panel == $panelName) {
    $result[$obj->{'last name'}] = $obj;
}

ksort($result);
```

But I would use a different way to create the agenda object.

```
<?php
class Panelist {
    private $_agenda = null;

    public function put($csv) {

        if (!file_exists($csv)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (($handle = fopen($csv, "r")) !== FALSE) {
            $row = 1;
            $count = 0;
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                if ($row == 1) {
                    $label = $data;
                    $count = count($data);
                } else {
                    if (count($data) == $count) {
                        for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
                            $agenda[$row][trim(strtolower($label[$i]))] = trim(strtolower($data[$i]));
                        }                       
                    }
                }
                $row++;
            }
            fclose($handle);
            $this->_agenda = json_decode(json_encode($agenda));
            return $this;
        }
    }

    public function get($label, $value) {
        $result = [];
        if (!property_exists($this, '_agenda')) {
            return false;
        }
        foreach ($this->_agenda as $item) {
            // loop through agenda for match values by label
            if (!empty($item->{$label}) && !empty($item->{'last name'}) && $item->{$label} == $value) {
                // arrange $result key with last name;
                $result[$item->{'last name'}] = $item;
            }
        }
        // sort $result by key with ascending order
        ksort($result);
        return $result;
    }
}

$panelist = new Panelist;

if ($agenda = $panelist->put("agenda.csv")->get('panel', 'tuesday')) {
    foreach ($agenda as $item) {
        echo $item->name . '<br>';
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

bill
john
samatha
jane